# finding out the device name for a given file

Tags: linux, filesystems

I was trying to figure this out but found myself clueless: How can I figure out the name of the device (e.g. /dev/sdb2) for a given file/inode? e.g.

```
[root@serv07 /]# ls -i /etc/passwd
38357228 /etc/passwd
```

Now, I know that inode 38357228 (or passwd) resides on /dev/sda2 but how can I figure that out for any given/random file(s)? Any help would be useful. Cheers!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `df`

```
df -P filename
```

will give you something like:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      280496152 31269088 235090852  12% /
```

`-P` is `--portability` to get POSIX output

Just to be convenient:

```
df -P filename | awk 'NR==2{print $1}'
```

Will give you just the device

Answer (score 2):

You can get the mount point for a given file with stat:

```
$ stat -c '%m' /etc/fstab
/
```

You can use this to look up what is mounted there using /proc/mounts

```
awk '$2 == "/"'  /proc/mounts
```

Comment: I don't see any `%m` format option in my version of stat; tried on RHEL/CentOS and Ubuntu - none of them has that. What distro are you on? Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `stat` command. See this question on Stack Exchange for the gory details:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309882/device-number-in-stat-command-output